# Configure custom SSL certificate for RDP on Windows Server 2012 (and later) in Remote Administration mode?

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016, rdp, remote-desktop-services

So the release of Windows Server 2012 has removed a lot of the old Remote Desktop related configuration utilities.  In particular, there is no more *Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration* utility that gave you access to the RDP-Tcp properties dialog that let you configure a custom certificate for the RDSH to use.  In its place is a nice new consolidated GUI that is part of the overall "edit deployment properties" workflow in the new Server Manager.  The catch is that you only get access to that workflow if you have the Remote Desktop Services role installed (as far as I can tell).

This seems like a bit of an oversight on Microsoft's part. How can we configure a custom SSL certificate for RDP on Windows Server 2012 when it's running in the default Remote Administration mode without needlessly installing the Remote Desktop Services role?

Comment: Related --> https://superuser.com/questions/1093159/how-to-provide-a-verified-server-certificate-for-remote-desktop-rdp-connection/1471991#1471991

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It turns out that much of the configuration data for RDSH is stored in the `Win32_TSGeneralSetting` class in WMI in the `root\cimv2\TerminalServices` namespace. The configured certificate for a given connection is referenced by the Thumbprint value of that certificate on a property called `SSLCertificateSHA1Hash`.

---

**UPDATE:** Here's a generalized Powershell solution that grabs and sets the thumbprint of the first SSL cert in the computer's personal store. If your system has multiple certs, you should add a `-Filter` option to the `gci` command to make sure you reference the correct cert. I've left my original answer intact below this for reference.

```
# get a reference to the config instance
$tsgs = gwmi -class "Win32_TSGeneralSetting" -Namespace root\cimv2\terminalservices -Filter "TerminalName='RDP-tcp'"

# grab the thumbprint of the first SSL cert in the computer store
$thumb = (gci -path cert:/LocalMachine/My | select -first 1).Thumbprint

# set the new thumbprint value
swmi -path $tsgs.__path -argument @{SSLCertificateSHA1Hash="$thumb"}
```

---

In order to get the thumbprint value

1. Open the properties dialog for your certificate and select the Details tab
2. Scroll down to the Thumbprint field and copy the space delimited hex string into something like Notepad
3. Remove all the spaces from the string. You'll also want to watch out for and remove a non-ascii character that sometimes gets copied just before the first character in the string. It's not visible in Notepad.
4. This is the value you need to set in WMI. It should look something like this: *1ea1fd5b25b8c327be2c4e4852263efdb4d16af4*.

Now that you have the thumbprint value, here's a one-liner you can use to set the value using wmic:

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\cimv2\TerminalServices PATH Win32_TSGeneralSetting Set SSLCertificateSHA1Hash="THUMBPRINT"
```

Or if PowerShell is your thing, you can use this instead:

```
$path = (Get-WmiObject -class "Win32_TSGeneralSetting" -Namespace root\cimv2\terminalservices -Filter "TerminalName='RDP-tcp'").__path
Set-WmiInstance -Path $path -argument @{SSLCertificateSHA1Hash="THUMBPRINT"}
```

**Note:** the certificate must be in the 'Personal' Certificate Store for the Computer account.

Comment: Just wanted to add that this saved me from pure meltdown. Thank you. Installing the roles and restarting servers as suggested within technet and the like is ridiculous. Even then, once you install the SSL cert in RD Gateway Manager, it doesn't carry over to the remote admin login.

Comment: You're most welcome.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I must've searched **all of google** before I found this. There are too many results telling me to install "Remote Desktop Services" via "Add roles and features", but doing so requires you to join a domain.

Comment: This is outstanding, so helpful, and should of course be provided by Microsoft.  Thanks for taking the time to post it here.

Comment: What happens if your certificate renews automatically, if you set this value? Will it automatically pick up the new hash? Also, can I delete the self-signed cert out of the RDP certificate folder?

Comment: I don't think it will automatically update the hash reference, but I've never tested so I can't be sure.  You can delete the self-signed cert, but in my experience Windows just re-creates a new one later.

Comment: @RyanBolger I'm about to renew the cert and was wondering if the thumbprint changes? After some reading, it appears it shouldn't, but wanted to know if you have experience with this?

Comment: I don't recall specifically, but I'm pretty sure it does because it's effectively a new cert.

Comment: The Command Prompt version didn't work for me on Windows Server 2012 R2 but the PowerShell version worked perfectly.

Comment: You might try posting a separate question with the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: It is possible to use a SHA256 certificate? I'm getting an "invalid argument" error.

Comment: Yes, any certificates that Windows supports should work. I personally use it with plenty of SHA256 certificates.

Comment: @doug-wilson Curiously, the command prompt version worked for me but the powershell version did not work.

Comment: If I try to do it using your PS script I get "Invalid Parameter". Same issue if I do it manually, too...

Comment: Which line gives you that error?

Comment: I was getting **Invalid argument** using all methods until I've re-imported certificate _including_ private keys. Simple mistake.

Comment: Me again :D I'm getting that "Invalid parameter" error in Powershell too when running `wmic`. Just seen the note at the bottom. **Make sure the cert is in the Personal store too.** Mine was in the Web Hosting store this time...

Comment: You can use SHA256 or other certificates, but the **thumbprint is SHA1**. Make sure you don't confuse serial number and thumbprint. PS. Tested the command prompt version on Windows Server 2016.

Comment: Me again, again. I had a script running this after renewing my Let's Encrypt certificates... It was working well for a long time -- now I'm getting `Security negotiation Error: CredSSPRequired(5)` when trying to connect and am now locked out -- anyone else received this error?

Comment: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=866660

Answer (score 5):

If you getting "Invalid Parameter" when you trying Ryan's solution, make sure you are using elevated command prompt (run as administrator).

Comment: Can't believe this has no upvote!

Answer (score 0):

You need your `domain.pfx`  & the fingerprint in a txt file `SSLCertificateSHA1Hash.txt`.

Then run this in CMD:

```
pushd %~dp0
cls
::FreeSoftwareServers.com

certutil.exe -p "" -importpfx "%~dp0domain.pfx"
set /p FingerPrint=<"%~dp0SSLCertificateSHA1Hash.txt"
wmic /namespace:\\root\CIMV2\TerminalServices PATH Win32_TSGeneralSetting Set SSLCertificateSHA1Hash="%FingerPrint%"
icacls.exe "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\*" /grant "NETWORK SERVICE":R
shutdown /r /t 5
```