# Attach certificate to remote desktop connection - not gateway services

Tags: ssl, rdp, certificate

I have a Windows server that I want to attach a 3rd party signed certificate for remote desktop connections. This is not a remote desktop services server, i.e. it is just remote desktop administration. There is lots of info on the internet about attaching a certificate to remote desktop services, but I want to attach mine to just plain remote desktop connection for administration purposes.

If anyone know how to do this, please holler! I have imported the certificate into the Remote Desktop store in the certificates mmc snap in, and have tried running the wmic command in this question ([Configure custom SSL certificate for RDP on Windows Server 2012 in Remote Administration mode?](https://serverfault.com/questions/444286/configure-custom-ssl-certificate-for-rdp-on-windows-server-2012-in-remote-admini)) but this fails.

THANKS!

Comment: When you imported the certificate, you imported it into the Computer store right?  The certificate you imported included the private key?  Did you get any errors when you tried following the method from the linked question?

Comment: Yes, i definitely imported it in to the computer store. Not too sure about private key, ill need to check. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, so I'm assuming you've likely either found a workaround or abandoned the attempt, but maybe it'll help someone else.

In order for the WMIC commands listed in the question you are looking at to work, the certificate needs to be in the "Local Computer -> Personal" store, not in the "Local Computer -> Remote Desktop" store. Since you said you put the certificate in the "Remote Desktop" store, the server cannot find it when you run the WMIC command.